# Move the laravel application While change the php version and Xampp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have install laravel 5.2 in my xampp3.2.2 and  php v7.0.2 but now i want to change the xampp with php version 5.6. what should i do to to running my laravel application in new xampp.

Comment: Just install it and move all the files in xampp with `php version 5.6` `httdocs`, simlple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Sanjog before you proceed, ensure that you have the backup.

1. As for Laravel application, it will be inside the 'www'/'htdocs' folder. Hence first take the backup of your Laravel Application
2. Take the SQL dump from your MySQL database. This will ensure that you have the proper backup to restore in the later stage.

Now, to downgrade to PHP 5.6, you can do two things.

1. WAMPP supports working with multiple PHP Versions. So you can download the PHP 5.6 and place in the 'WAMPP/bin/php' folder and change the path of PHP Library in your Apache Configuration. But this is a tedious job, as you need to later install all the PHP Modules for 5.6
2. You can completely un-install the WAMPP and install the WAMPP which ships with PHP 5.6. This is very quick and easy job.

In the 1st way, you need not change anything about Laravel Project, as nothing will be changed. But you are installing the PHP 5.6 and configuring manually.

In the 2nd way, after you do the fresh install, you need to restore your Laravel Project in the 'htdocs' folder and you need to restore your database into MySQL.

Comment: You can refer the following SO Post to know as how to configure WAMPP to work with multiple PHP Versions - http://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php, but be careful if you are choosing this route.